# How can I find a parametrization?

Tags: calculus

We have $\Gamma$ the intersection of the superior hemisphere of sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and the cylinder $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$.

I need to find a parametrization $\gamma :[a,b]\to \mathbb{R} ^3$ positively oriented.

Any hint?

Comment: let $x-1=\cos t, y=\sin t$ and $z=\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$ (or use some other parameterization of the circle)

Comment: Here, you take $[a,b] = [0,\pi ]$?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to graph them and look at the intersection. That doesn't generalize well, but it would work for this. You'd get a solution like yoyo's, which is very clean and easy to deal with.

Another is just algebra-bashing:
$$(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$$
$$y^2 = 1 - (x-1)^2$$
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$$
$$x^2 + 1 - (x-1)^2 + z^2 = 4$$
$$2x + z^2 = 4$$
$$2x = 4 - z^2$$
$$x = \frac{1}{2}(4 - z^2)$$
Let $t$ = $z$. So now we can compute $x$ and $z$ in terms of $t$. Substituting back into the first equation lets us find $y$ too.
$$(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$$
$$(\frac{1}{2}(4 - t^2)-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$$
$$y^2 = 1 - (\frac{1}{2}(4 - t^2 -2))^2$$
$$y^2 = 1 - \frac{1}{4}(2 - t^2)^2$$
$$y^2 = 1 - \frac{1}{4}(4 - 4t^2 + t^4)$$
$$y^2 = 1 - 1 + t^2 - \frac{1}{4}t^4$$
$$y^2 = t^2 - \frac{1}{4}t^4$$

In hindsight this is an awful idea.